# jQuery .change event not firing for ASP MVC CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Below is the jQuery code I'm trying to use to make a hidden text box visible. However when clicked the text box stays hidden, and none of the `alerts` will fire.

For this check box I have tried `.click`, `.change`, and `.mousedown` however none has worked.

Here is the jQuery

```
$('#OverrideRegionInd').click(function () {
    alert("here");
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#territoryName').html("");
        $('#Region').val("");
        $('#Region').show();
    } else {

    }
});
```

And here is the code from the view. This is an ASP MVC 3 site

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        Override Territory Manually?
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field" style="padding-right:190px;padding-top:5px;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.OverrideRegionInd)
    </div>
```

EDIT

Here is the entire `<div>` after it is rendered

```
    <div class="M-editor-field" style="padding-right:190px;padding-top:5px;">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Override Territory? field is required." id="OverrideRegionInd" name="OverrideRegionInd" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="OverrideRegionInd" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </div>
```

Comment: inspect the html. does the checkbox have an ID

Comment: Show me the HTML that rendered

Comment: Make sure your JQuery is loaded after the HTML is rendered. Wrap it in a $(document).ready(function () { //your javascript code });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted (and the resulting HTML) works **exactly as is** (see Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YYBL4/))

The only difference, is JSFiddle wraps that jQuery into a `document.ready` call, try that:

```
$(function () {
    $('#OverrideRegionInd').click(function () {
       //click function code
    });
});
```

Comment: Putting this code inside the `document.ready` made it work. Any idea why it won't work outside of it? (I just started learning jQuery on the job about a week ago)

Comment: @NealR Because there's no guarantee that the DOM has fully loaded when this code executes (in your case it hadn't), so you should always use `document.ready` (similar to `window.onload` in pure JavaScript).